# Sequencing in RxJS results in "out of memory" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, rxjs, reactive-programming

I need to process 1 million lines of record, transform each one of them, and save them to multiple files (binned by the hour; 1 file for each hour -- I'm thinking of splitting them by "filter").

For some reason I need those lines to be processed strictly sequentially. Meaning, if line #450000 takes longer to process and to save (this is the tricky part because fs is async with callback), the processing wouldn't jump to #450001... It will wait until 450000 is finished. That random sleeping in the code is to simulate that scenario.

Previously (with simple Promise, no RxJs), I would create N promises, one for each line, keep them in an array, and do the chaining by reduce op, as explained here: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

But I don't want to create 1 million instances of Promises. So, I looked into ReactiveX, hoping that it will be like "pass the buck"; meaning it wouldn't wait, the processing would take place as soon as an event pops-up, and the resource used by the processing (thinking that the processing block is basically a promise behind the scene) will be released as soon as possible.

I tried to verify that with this code:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs-es6/Rx';
import Q from 'q';    

let subject = new Rx.Subject();
let processEventJsons = function(observable) {
  observable.concatMap(eventJson => {
    let deferred = Q.defer();    

    setTimeout(() => {
      eventJson.procDatetime = new Date().toISOString();
      deferred.resolve(eventJson);
    }, Math.random() * 5000);    

    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(deferred.promise)
  })
  .subscribe({
    next: enrichedEventJson => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(enrichedEventJson));
    },
    error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
    complete: () => console.log('done'),
  });
}    

processEventJsons(
  subject.filter(dataJson => dataJson.type === "interview").map(dataJson => {
    return {event: "intv", datetime: dataJson.datetime}
  })
)    

processEventJsons(
  subject.filter(dataJson => dataJson.type === "checkin").map(dataJson => {
    return {event: "chki", datetime: dataJson.datetime}
  })
)    

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    subject.next({id: i, type: "interview", datetime: new Date().toISOString()});
  } else {
    subject.next({id: i, type: "checkin", datetime: new Date().toISOString()});
  }
}
subject.complete();
```

But... I kept getting:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.

The console.log(JSON.stringify(enrichedEventJson)); doesn't get printed until the "for-loop" (at the end of the code) is completed.

This makes me think that switching to RxJS hasn't really improved the situation; it still queues-up promises behind the scene.

Or am I using the API wrongly? Can you help me point out what's wrong?

### UPDATE UPDATE:

False Flag. Figured out the problem is not the in the use of RxJS, but in the for-loop (it's too tight). SO I changed it to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      subject.next({id: i, type: "interview", datetime: new Date().toISOString()});
    });
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      subject.next({id: i, type: "checkin", datetime: new Date().toISOString()});
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would create N promises, one for each line, keep them in an array, and do the chaining by reduce op

That's the simple but memory-hungry approach. It uses a million promises that need to exist at the same time. Instead, you can use a recursive approach to process your lines sequentially in constant memory:

```
function getInput(i) {
  return {id: i, type: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "interview" : "checkin", datetime: new Date().toISOString()};
}
function process(eventJson) {
  let deferred = Q.defer();    
  setTimeout(() => {
    eventJson.procDatetime = new Date().toISOString();
    deferred.resolve(eventJson);
  }, Math.random() * 5000);    
  return deferred.promise;
}
function filteredProcess({type, datetime}) {
  if (type === "interview")
    return process({event: "intv", datetime});
  if (type === "checkin")
    return process({event: "chki", datetime});
}
function log(enrichedEventJson) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(enrichedEventJson));
}

function loop(i) {
  if (i < 1000000)
    return getInput(i)
    .then(filteredProcess)
    .then(log)
    .then(() => loop(i+1));
  else
    return Q("done")
}

loop().then(console.log, err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err));
```